# Asynchronous XmlReader in .NET?

Tags: c#, xml, xmpp

Is there a way to access a XmlReader asynchronously? The xml is coming in off the network from many different clients like in XMPP; it is a constant stream of `<action>...</action`> tags.

What i'm after is to be able to use a BeginRead/EndRead-like interface. The best solution I've managed to come up with is to do an asynchronous read for 0 bytes on the underlying network stream, then when some data arrives, call Read on the XmlReader- this will however block until all of the data from the node becomes available. That solution looks roughly like this

```
private Stream syncstream;
private NetworkStream ns;
private XmlReader reader;

//this code runs first
public void Init()
{
    syncstream = Stream.Synchronized(ns);
    reader = XmlReader.Create(syncstream);
    byte[] x = new byte[1];
    syncstream.BeginRead(x, 0, 0, new AsynchronousCallback(ReadCallback), null);
}

private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    syncstream.EndRead(ar);
    reader.Read(); //this will block for a while, until the entire node is available
    //do soemthing to the xml node
    byte[] x = new byte[1];
    syncstream.BeginRead(x, 0, 0, new AsynchronousCallback(ReadCallback), null);
}
```

EDIT: This is a possible algorithm for working out if a string contains a complete xml node?

```
Func<string, bool> nodeChecker = currentBuffer =>
                {
                    //if there is nothing, definetly no tag
                    if (currentBuffer == "") return false;
                    //if we have <![CDATA[ and not ]]>, hold on, else pass it on
                    if (currentBuffer.Contains("<![CDATA[") && !currentBuffer.Contains("]]>")) return false;
                    if (currentBuffer.Contains("<![CDATA[") && currentBuffer.Contains("]]>")) return true;
                    //these tag-related things will also catch <? ?> processing instructions
                    //if there is a < but no >, we still have an open tag
                    if (currentBuffer.Contains("<") && !currentBuffer.Contains(">")) return false;
                //if there is a <...>, we have a complete element.
                //>...< will never happen because we will pass it on to the parser when we get to >
                if (currentBuffer.Contains("<") && currentBuffer.Contains(">")) return true;
                //if there is no < >, we have a complete text node
                if (!currentBuffer.Contains("<") && !currentBuffer.Contains(">")) return true;
                //> and no < will never happen, we will pass it on to the parser when we get to >
                //by default, don't block
                return false;
            };
```

Comment: your counter fails on this case, which is *perfectly* legal XML: <foo bar='>baz'/>, where the read boundary is before baz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlReader buffers in 4kB chunks, if I remember from when I looked in to this a couple of years ago.  You could pad your inbound data to 4kB (ick!), or use a better parser.  I fixed this by porting James Clark's XP (Java) to C# as a part of Jabber-Net, here:

http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/#svn/trunk/xpnet

It's LGPL, only handles UTF8, isn't packaged for use, and has almost no documentation, so I wouldn't recommend using it. :)

Comment: Could you give me a quick rundown on how to use this parser? Will multiple instances parse different sockets asynchronously without requiring their own thread? (like in xmpp?)

Comment: See:

http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/jabber/protocol/AsynchElementStream.cs

for an example.  Create a UTF8Encoding, throw bytes at it with tokenizeContent or tokenizeCdataSection, look at the tokens that come out.  Where the bytes come from, and the synchronization to ensure that you aren't modifying one parser's state on different threads is up to you.

If you want to do XMPP, you could just use all of Jabber-Net, and save yourself some hassle.

Comment: So, it would seem that the *general* solution is to find an xml parser with an interface that lets me put bytes into it myself at my leisure instead of supplying a stream. The parser will parse content as i supply it, keeping bytes that it has not parsed yet due to it not being a complete xml node. Sound about right?

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like xpnet is LGPL; the copying.txt file pretty much says you can do whatever you like with it. Am I missing something?

Comment: For your first question: yes.  Expat is a great example of such a parser.

For your second, the intent was that the C# port was LGPL, but I included James Clark's copying.txt due to this text:

  "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."

The port is close enough to the original XP code that I figured I'd keep the copying.txt file to be safe.

Comment: Ahk. Well, LGPL is fine for me, so I'll have a shot at using your c# port of expat. I suppose that makes this the answer i was looking for :P Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

`XmlReader` in .NET 4.5 has **async** versions of most of the methods that would involve IO.

Check the sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is just put it on another thread, perhaps a ThreadPool depending on how long it stays active.  (Don't use thread pool threads for truly long-running tasks).

Comment: It doesn't.  I didn't necessarily say one thread per client :)

Comment: So if every client had it's own xml stream for the life of the connection, how would you avoid having each XmlReader in it's own thread?

Comment: Job queues?  How are these streams supposed to combine?

Answer (score 1):

This is really tricky, because `XmlReader` doesn't provide any asynchronous interface.

I'm not really sure how much asynchronously does the `BeginRead` behave when you ask it to read 0 bytes - it might as well invoke the callback immediately and then block when you call `Read`. This could be the same thing as calling `Read` directly and then scheduling the next `Read` in a thread pool for example using `QueueWorkItem`.

It may be better to use `BeginRead` on the network stream to read data for example in 10kB chunks (while the system waits for the data, you wouldn't be blocking any thread). When you receive a chunk, you would copy it into some local `MemoryStream` and your `XmlReader` would be reading data from this `MemoryStream`.

This still has a problem though - after copying 10kB of data and calling `Read` several times, the last call would block. Then you would probably need to copy smaller chunks of data to unblock the pending call to `Read`. Once that's done, you could again start a new `BeginRead` call to read larger portion of data asynchronously.

Honestly, this sounds pretty complicated, so I'm quite interested if anybody comes up with a better answer. However, it gives you at least some guaranteed asynchronous operations that take some time and do not block any threads in the meantime (which is the essential goal of asynchronous programming).

(**Side note:** You could try using [F# asynchronous workflows](http://www.infoq.com/articles/pickering-fsharp-async) to write this, because they make asynchronous code a lot simpler. The technique I described will be tricky even in F# though)

Comment: I threw together a quick test and BeginRead'ing 0 bytes is perfectly fine, the callback isn't invoked until some data is ready. I'll have a shot at your algorithm now

Comment: Also, if i knew the message length, the problem you describe wouldn't exist, would it?

Comment: If BeginRead makes it wait for at least some data then it's probably okay (if you're downloading small chunks). If you knew the message (one <action> item) length, then you could read exactly the ammount of bytes needed to perform the next `Read` call. But this may be still problematic (e.g. with different text encodings, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, Ideally what i'd want is some way of buffering up received data until there's enough to read the next node without blocking.
I'll post what i'm thinking as an edit to my question...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like DOT NET 4.5 has an `bool Async` property on XmlReader, that is not there in 3.5.  Maybe that will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the [XamlReader.LoadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346591.aspx) method?

> An asynchronous XAML load operation
>   will initially return an object that
>   is purely the root object.
>   Asynchronously, XAML parsing then
>   continues, and any child objects are
>   filled in under the root.

Comment: I don't think XamlReader fires events when new nodes become available, only when it has completed loading the markup, which, in my case, would be when the connection is closed. Would be an interesting use of xaml though :P

Comment: Thought as much. Leaving my answer up though in case it helps someone else later...