# Why does my Inject method not inject data to the stream?

Tags: c#, stream

I've written a wrapper class for C# `Stream` because I want it to be able to inject data to the stream and call a function whenever data is read via ReadAsync(). However the "inject" part does not work and I have no idea why.

```
class ExtendedStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _originalStream;
    private readonly Action<byte[]> _readCallback;

    private ManualResetEvent dataInjected = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
    private int pos = 0;

    public ExtendedStream(Stream originalStream, Action<byte[]> readCallback)
    {
        _originalStream = originalStream;
        _readCallback = readCallback;
    }

    public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var read = await _originalStream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);

        _readCallback(buffer);

        return read;
    }

    public void Inject(string text)
    {
        data.AddRange(new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(text));
        dataInjected.Set();
    }

    private IEnumerable<byte> GetBytes(int count)
    {
        int returned = 0;

        while (returned == 0)
        {
            if (pos < data.Count)
            {
                while (pos < data.Count && returned < count)
                {
                    yield return data[pos];

                    pos += 1; returned += 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataInjected.Reset();
                dataInjected.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }       

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var bytes = GetBytes(count).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; offset + i < buffer.Length && i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            buffer[offset + i] = bytes[i];
        }

        return bytes.Length;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _originalStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return _originalStream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return _originalStream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return _originalStream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override void Flush() 
    {
        _originalStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return _originalStream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return _originalStream.Position; }
        set { _originalStream.Position = value; }
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _originalStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _originalStream.SetLength(value);
    }        
}
```

Then I am reading the stream with XmlReader like follows.

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(_extendedStream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
{
                while (await xmlReader.ReadAsync())
                {                        
                    switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
                    {                            
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            if (xmlReader.LocalName.Equals("test"))
                            {
                                _log.Debug("</test> injected!");                            
                            }
                            break;
                        default:                              
                            break;
                    }
}
```

The data is never injected if I call `_extendedStream.Inject("</test>")`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your `ReadAsync` method delegates to `_originalStream.ReadAsync`, so I don't think your overridden `Read` method (where the injection magic happens) ever gets invoked in your sample code. Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Mhm... yes I did go through the code with the debugger. I was of the opinion (don't ask me why) that `ReadAsync` uses `Read` like suggested in the example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015279/disposing-of-xmlreader-with-pending-async-read. How do I override `ReadAsync` (an example would be super)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReadAsync` method delegates to `_originalStream.ReadAsync`, so I don't think your overridden `Read` method (where the injection magic happens) ever gets invoked in your sample code.

Rather than overriding `ReadAsync` (which could get complicated), you could move the read of the original stream into your `Read` method, which will be invoked asynchronously by the base `ReadAsync` method.

```
// UNTESTED CODE, MAY CONTAIN OFF BY ONE ERRORS
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    var bytes = GetBytes(count).ToArray();

    // write injected bytes into buffer
    for (int i = 0; offset + i < buffer.Length && i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[offset + i] = bytes[i];
    }

    if(bytes.Length < count)
    {
        // we reached the end of the custom bytes, so read the rest from the original stream
        count = count - bytes.Length;
        offset += bytes.Length;
        totalBytesRead = _originalStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    totalBytesRead += bytes.Length;

    _readCallback(buffer);

    return totalBytesRead;
}
```

That may need some tweaking to prevent your injected data from being injected over and over again, but at least the injection logic will be running.