Working with XML in chunks node js using sax js
I try using sax js in order to process xml file in chunks , adding it to limited size of array ,  await to updating the DB , then reset the array.
The problem is that it not working asynchronously out of the box and didnt find yet the solution to update DB without loosing data
I'm using the lts version of  sax js
const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
const xmlStream = fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(gunzip);
const saxStream = sax.createStream(true);
const BATCH_SIZE = 100;



let documents = [];
let currentElement = {};
let currentNode = null; 
let isProcessing = false;


saxStream.on("opentag", function (node) {
    currentNode = node.name;
    if (node.name === "Item") {
      currentElement = {}; // Initialize a new empty object for each item
    }
  });

saxStream.on("text", (text) => {
    if (currentElement) {
      doSomthing(text)
    }
  });

saxStream.on("closetag", async function (name) {
    if (name === "Item" && currentElement && documents.length < BATCH_SIZE) {
      documents.push(currentElement );
      currentElement = {}; // Reset for the next item

      if (documents.length === BATCH_SIZE && !isProcessing) {
        isProcessing = true;
        console.log("1. Start process batch of size", documents.length);
        await insertDocuments(documents);
        console.log("1. End process batch of size", documents.length);
        documents = []; // Reset the documents array after processing
        isProcessing = false;
      }
    }

    currentNode = null; // Reset the current node name
  });


xmlStream.pipe(saxStream);


So ofc it doesnt await to the insertDocuments and continue
so I tried to combined pausing the stream using xmlStream.pause() and xmlStream.resume() before and after the async method
 if (documents.length === BATCH_SIZE && !isProcessing) {
        isProcessing = true;
        xmlStream.pause();
        console.log("1. Start process batch of size", documents.length);
        await insertDocuments(documents);
        console.log("1. End process batch of size", documents.length);
        documents = []; // Reset the documents array after processing
        isProcessing = false;
        xmlStream.resume();
      }


its not good solution due to we stop the xmlStream but not the sax stream and then we loosing data .
I also tried using this._parser.close() and this._parser.resume() and couldn't find any solution .
The output of logs of this code is :

Start process batch of size 100
processed:  100
End process batch of size 100
start process batch of size 17
processed:  17
End process batch of size 17
XML parsing completed.

** in the test I used small file
while the total items are 133 as we can see 16 items not processed

It might be useful to identify exactly which XML parser (and version) you are using; I believe there are several.

I am using sax js lts version. but I'm open to change to other library that well maintained and perform fast parsing. (already updated it in body of the main query)

Why are you reading in chunks?  Is it due to out of memory or are you trying to process while data is being received?  You can convert the following c# to Powershell : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263852/asynchronous-xmlreader-in-net

@jdweng im processing chunk in order to reduce memory

Use Powershell with XmlReader to reduce the memory.  See sample code below
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$xmlFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($csvFilename)

$writer.WriteLine('time,linkID,CO,CO2Total')

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($xmlFilename)
While(-not $reader.EOF)
{
    if($reader.Name -ne 'event')
    {
        $reader.ReadToFollowing('event') | out-null;
    }
    if(-not $reader.EOF)
    {
        $event = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement][System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader);
        $type = $event.Attribute('type').Value
        if($type -eq 'warmEmissionEvent')
        {
           $time = $event.Attribute('type').Value
           $linkId = $event.Attribute('linkId').Value
           $CO = $event.Attribute('CO').Value
           $CO2Total = $event.Attribute('CO2_TOTAL').Value
           $writer.WriteLine([string]::Join(',',@($time,$linkId,$CO,$CO2Total)))
        }
    }
}
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Close()


I need it in node js

You can run powershell from inside js : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002794/in-javascript-how-to-call-powershell-script
